# How to make a std. library

Tags: python, import, shared-libraries, static-libraries, python-import

I want to use the "kconfiglib" for python, but I get an "ImportError" when executing. Kconfiglib comes with some examples like:

```
#! /bin/python
# Prints the names of all symbols that reference a particular symbol. (There's
# also a method get_selected_symbols() for determining just selection
# relations.)

import kconfiglib
import sys

conf = kconfiglib.Config(sys.argv[1])

x86 = conf["X86"]
for sym in conf:
    if x86 in sym.get_referenced_symbols():
        print sym.get_name()
```

when running this the following error appears:

```
ImportError: no module named kconfiglib
```

so I guess the kconfiglib isn't installed as a std. lib. But how can I change it? I was looking for a solution in the internet but they are mostly about similiar libraries that failed to import, and their solution is usually installing a new "rpm". But AFAIK there isn't a rpm for the kconfiglib.

So I need a solution to do this the "hard-code" way. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks for your support

Comment: Did you try the [instructions](https://github.com/ulfalizer/Kconfiglib#installation)? You may need to install [Git](http://git-scm.com/) first.

Comment: leads to rather more disturbing errror messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to call the script with python, not as a shell:

---> **python** /path-to-script/script.py

Comment: actually my question is **not** answered but the problem is solved